# Создание объекта модели с полем ManyToMany в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, many-to-many

Есть две модели в `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=50)
    desc = models.TextField('Описание')
    
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Автор', max_length=50)
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post, verbose_name='Пост')
```

Объекты модели `Post` создаются без проблем, и в базе они есть. В `admin.py` пытаюсь создать модель `Author`:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj = Author.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'])  # Ошибка в этой строке              
        obj.post.add(request.POST['post'])
        obj.save()
```

***Ошибка:*** `NOT NULL constraint failed: author_author.post_id.`

Я понимаю, что он не может создать объект `Author`, так как для поля `ManyToMany` нужен `id` этого объекта. Но у меня его просто создать не получается.

Также делала `obj.name = request.POST['name']; obj.save()`, результат тот же.

Comment: Также делала `obj.name = request.POST['name']; obj.save()` результат тот же

Comment: Метод `objects.create` создаёт и сразу пытается **сохранить** объект (вызывая `save`). Но ключа на `Post` нет, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Comment: Либо создавайте `Post` заранее и передавайте в `objects.create`, либо не сохраняйте `Author` до тех пор, пока не получите `Post`. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [пример сохранения](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#field-options) из документации (без `objects.create`).

Comment: Объекты модели `Post` уже созданы и я их могу выбирать при создании `Author`. Пробовала писать `obj=Author(name=request.POST['name'])` и `obj.save()`, а затем `obj.post.add(request.POST['post'])`, но на методе `save()` снова та же ошибка.

Comment: Вы вызывали `obj.save()` до того, как добавляли `Post`? Если так, то сохраняйте `Author` в самом конце; инструкция `obj.save()` должна быть **последней**. Попробуйте так: `obj = Author(name=request.POST['name']); obj.post.add(request.POST['post']); obj.save()`.

Comment: Теперь ошибка "needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.". В `request.POST['post']` значение есть. Такую ошибку выдает даже если просто вызвать `obj.post`

Comment: Я так понимаю, в `request.POST['post']` просто данные? Если так, то сначала создайте из этих данных класс `post = Post(...)`, а уже потом добавляйте `post` в `obj`.

Comment: Сделала так, но ошибка "needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used." осталась

Comment: а зачем у вас в авторе поле ManyToMany? не проще ли создать аналогичное поле в модели поста? ведь автор может существовать без постов (как правило автор == юзер), а вот пост без автора не может. И почему ManyToMany? у поста разве бывает несколько авторов?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Автор', max_length=50)
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post, verbose_name='Пост', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Да, это избавляет от ошибки, но хотелось бы что бы поле осталось обязательным

Comment: Окей, для того что бы создать объект Author не нужно переписывать функцию save_model. Если речь конечно идёт именно о создании через admin.py

Comment: да в принципе без разницы, через что создавать. Главное, чтобы объект вместе с полем manyToMany создавался без ошибок, ну и по хорошему, чтобы это поле оставалось обязательным